# List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm working on a project that involves processing large datasets using nested list comprehensions in Python. The code I've written achieves the desired result, but I'm concerned about its performance as the dataset size increases. I'm looking for suggestions on how to optimize the code for better efficiency

```
result = [
    [func1(item) for item in sublist1 if condition1(item)]
    for sublist1 in dataset1
    if condition2(sublist1)
    for sublist2 in dataset2
    if condition3(sublist2)
]
```

Comment: First of all, this looks very much like abuse of list comprehension. IMHO, you shouldn't be doing this. There is little we can help with the information provided. Of course one can always work with generator,

Comment: first check how it work woth big dataset - maybe you don't have to worry. But if it work slow then you may have to find module which use C/C++ for this,

Comment: This looks like something you may want to do using numpy arrays depending on what the data looks like. Nested lists can be easily represented as ndimensional arrays and numpy provides a lot of fast convenience functions that let you apply conditions to filter data and to apply functions to transform data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a clear answer here as to how to optimize this code without knowing the actual context.

However there are some things I see or might help you.

- A list comprehension provides you with the full list in memory. This can be expensive if your list has many elements and/or big elements. If you need the resulting list only element-by-element for some other use you can consider using a `generator expression`. This is achieved by replacing the square brackets (`[]`) with round brackets (`()`). Now the full list will not be stored in memory and only calculated element-by-element when you loop over it for example.
- The if statements you use in between the nested `for loops` are already good to exclude loops as soon as possible.
- The first line of your comprehension is another comprehension, which can definitely be a big impact on your performance. However, you mention the code does exactly what you need it to do.

In general if you need to speed up your code you can consider using a profiler such as `pyinstrument` to identify which part of your code actually takes the longest amount of time.